# How can I make my unordered list to paging using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to know how can I make my `<ul>` to paging?

Example: prev 1 2 3 4 5 next

when I click next it will go like this

prev 2 3 4 5 6 next

when I click prev it will go like this

prev 1 2 3 4 5 next

and so on...

```
<ul class="pages">
 <li>Prev</li>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
 <li>8</li>
 <li>9</li>
 <li>10</li>
 <li>Next</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you written any code so far which you can show us?

Comment: I've tried to use pajinate plugin but it is different from what I actually need since the paging was base on the number of li's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `:gt(n)//n denotes number`

```
$(function (){
     $("li:gt(5)").css("display", "none");
        });​
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tpBdc/5/)

If you want to see from 6 to 10 element then you can

```
$(function (){
     $("li:lt(6)").css("display", "none");
        });​
```

Comment: It is possible to include the Next? and everytime the next will be clicked the 6th li will show and 1st li will hide and so on :3

Comment: @SuiGo DO try and if you get stuck then we would help you out but first you tried by yourself...

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery [**.nextUntil()**](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [**.prevUntil()**](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/)

These links already have demos

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), such that:

```
$(".pages li").slice(5).css("display", "none");
```

However this will include your "next" item, but with jQuery you could easily count the `li`s and exclude the last index - an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What's wrong with your jsfiddle is that it's using Mootools and not importing jQuery. Here's [an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/tpBdc/4/).

Comment: sorry, how can I include the Next and when click next the 6th will show and when I click the prev it will go backwards :3

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS function that I created:

```
        function showPage (pageIndex, pageSize) {
            var items = $(".pages > li");
            $(items).hide();

            // Range
            var start = pageIndex * pageSize;
            var end = start + pageSize;

            $(items).slice(start, end).show();

        }
```

Then call showPage(0, 10);  // PageNumber=1, PageSize=10